# How many outcomes are possible?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

An experiment consists of rolling three dice, and then choosing 2 cards at random from a standard deck of 52 cards. How many outcomes are possible?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am not sure how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the results of dices and cards are independent.

The number of possible results of dices is

$$
N_{d}=\binom{6}{3}+2\times\binom{6}{2}+\binom{6}{1}=56
$$

And the number of possible results of cards is

$$
N_c=\binom{52}{2}=1326
$$

So the number of possible outcomes is

$$
N_d\times N_c=74256
$$

Comment: why multiply 2 x 6C2?

Comment: $\binom{6}{2}$ corresponds to the numbers of possible combinations of two results of dices. 

We want to express situations that two dices are the same, and (A,A,B) and (A,B,B) are both possible, so we times two.

Comment: can you pls explain the number of possible result of dices

Comment: 3 dices are different: $\binom{6}{3}$.

Exactly 2 dices are the same: $2\times\binom{6}{2}$.

All dices are the same: $\binom{6}{1}$.